# The house numbers on a street each have 4 digits that range from 1000 to 9999. How many of these house numbers have exactly 2 digits that are 5?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

My problem with this question is the fact that the first number doesn't have as many choices as the last 3. I'm sure it's easier than I thing it is but I just can't get around it. I have 4C2 ways of picking where to put my 5s, but I now don't know how many ways I can pick and order the last 2 numbers because I won't know whether or not one of my 5s is in the first spot.

Comment: Welcome to MathStackExchange. Please try to provide some insight into your attempts to solving this problem (this is good practice on this website). As a comment, you have 8 options for the first number and 9 for all others, why is this a problem for you?

Comment: Well I have 4C2 ways of picking where to put my 5s, but I now don't know how many ways I can pick and order the last 2 numbers because I won't know whether or not one of my 5s is in the first spot. I will also edit my post to explain my problem, thank you.

Comment: Did you considered separating the case when you know the first digit to be five from the case you know the first digit isn't 5?

Comment: I tried earlier but couldn't work it out. I gave it another shot and this is what I came up with: 5 is always in the first spot, with 3C1 ways to put it somewhere in the last 3, and 10^2 ways to pick the remaining. Plus 9 options for the first spot and 10 for one of the others, with 3C2 ways to order the 5s. (3C1)*10 + 9*10*(3C2)

Comment: There are $9\cdot9=81$ possibilities for numbers of the form $55ab$ and $5ab5$;  $8\cdot9=72$ of the form $a5b5$ and $8\cdot9-1=71$ of the form $ab55$. There are not another form.

Answer (score 1):

**If the first digit is 5:**

1 combination for the first place. ->1

2 numbers other than five need to be picked with repetition.  ->$9^2$

3 positions are available between these 2 numbers to place the remaining "5" (._ . _ .)$ ->3

So $9^2 \times 3$ combinations here.

**If the first digit isn't 5:**

8 numbers available for the first digit -> 8

2 spots out of 3 for the two "5" digits (order irrelevant) -> 3

9 numbers available for for the remaining spot -> $9$

So $8 \times 3 \times 9 $ combinations here.